# how to use the regex findall list

Tags: python, regex, list

so i'm a js trainee and at my internship someone asked me to do something on the python code, but i never did something on Python so i'm a bit lost..
I would like to separate a string in differents block.

here is what i have :

```
    buffer = """
#<start>
    idothings
#</start>
#<params>
    otherthings
#</params>
#<end>
    andifinish
#</end>
```

what i would like is a regex that separate this string in differents parts :

```
separatedString = [["#<start>,"idothings","#</start>"],["#<params>,"otherthings","#</params>"],["#<end>,"andifinish","#</end>"]]
```

what i tried to do is that :

```
def getStructure(string):

    separatedString = re.findall('(#<.+?>)(.|\n)+?(#<\/.+?>)', string)
    return
```

but this gave me a list... and i don't understand how do i navigate through a list in python ...

```
[("#<start>", '\n', '#</start>'), ('#<azeaze>', '\n', '#</azeaze>'), ('#<sgdfs>', 'x', '#</sgdfs>')]
```

i tried :

```
print '\n'.join(["%s a %s et %s" %(p1,p2,p3) for p1, strings in separatedString ])
```

but it game me an error "too many values to unpack"

Can someone show me how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buffer = """#<start>
    idothings
#</start>
#<params>
    otherthings
#</params>
#<end>
    andifinish
#</end>"""

spl = buffer.splitlines()
print([spl[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(spl),3)])
[['#<start>', '    idothings', '#</start>'], ['#<params>', '    otherthings', '#</params>'], ['#<end>', '    andifinish', '#</end>']]




spl = buffer.splitlines()
sliced = [spl[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(spl),3)]

for a,b,c in sliced:
    print(a.strip(),b.strip(),c.striip())
('#<start>', 'idothings', '#</start>')
('#<params>', 'otherthings', '#</params>')
('#<end>', 'andifinish', '#</end>')
```

Comment: sliced  basically groups every three lines from buffer into lists, for a,b,c in sliced just unpacks each sublist :)

Comment: The string was splitted in line to make it more "visible" on the post, but it won't be like that all the time, your method won't work if the string is in only one line, isn't? but thx anyway, some lane of your code helped me understand :D

Comment: nope but the unpacking is the same. what actual output do you want?

Comment: the unpacking was the important thing anyway ;)
I will do the rest ;)

thx! have a good day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is a little faulty
. Try this instead

```
print '\n'.join(["%s a %s et %s" %(p1,p2,p3) for p1, p2, p3 in separatedString ])
```

You are getting an error because, you are trying to get two values from a tuple having three elements

```
for p1, strings in separatedString
```

Here `separatedString` has 3 elements in each of its members